# In Visual Studio Code, why does the it auto-create the "main::main and main::~main", besides the class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, c++17

So when using the "intellisense", when I want to create a class, it also creates those other two functions (not sure if I am calling them right):

```
class main
{
private:
    /* data */
public:
    main(/* args */);
    ~main();
};

main::main(/* args */)
{
}

main::~main()
{
}
```

Why is that? How are they useful and also is the "~" the bitwise NOT ?

Comment: Those are the constructor and destructor, they set up an object and clean it up afterwards. Look up those terms in your C++ textbook or any C++ guide.

Comment: You really need to take a step back and learn some very basic C++. Please go back to your text-books, tutorials or class and refresh your knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are special member functions,  a user-defined default constructor and user-defined destructor.

VS Code specifically does it because Microsoft corporate code style requires always to have constructor\destructor in class. To the point where in older versions of their compilers default initialization for trivial classes never was a value (zero) initialization (non-compliant with standard). C++ does not have such requirement in rules, this makes class not a trivial\POD.

As usual, their IDE does only half of job. With such spproach, one needs to define five functions, not two, see "rule of zero".

Comment: what a weird convention, declaring them `=default` would be cool, but this is just meh

Comment: @ideclev I agree, I had to live with those! They didn't support that feature until 2013 or late 2012 patch?

Comment: These are not default constructor and destructor, but simply a declaration of constructor and destructor.

Comment: @YevheniiMamontov not sure what you mean. "Default constructor" has a quite well defined meaning. It is a constructor that can be called without parameters, ie that constructor is a default constructor

Comment: @idclev463035818, sorry. I didn't notice the definition, you are completely right.

Comment: @YevheniiMamontov it's a user-supplied default constructor and a destructor. Use of "a" article is important to divide what "default" refers too. It's not `=default` (read as compiler-generated) constructor though.